# Why is my refrigerator regularly getting too cold?

Tags: refrigerator, samsung

Our Samsung RB215LASH refrigerator has had a persistent intermittent problem with the temperature in the refrigerator section getting too cold, causing stuff to freeze up. We see this even though we've set the temperature in the refrigerator is set to the maximum 46° Fahrenheit and the freezer is also set to the maximum 8° Fahrenheit. Neither superfreeze or super cool are turned on.

Previously we attributed this to the refrigerator being too full, blocking airflow, but it's doing it currently and the and it's definitely not too full.

I have a thermocouple in the refrigerator that is currently reading 34 degrees Fahrenheit right next to the temperature probe even though the temperature in the refrigerator is set to 46°.

I was going to test the thermistor using some instructions I found on YouTube but I was wondering if there's anything else I should look at.

Comment: This is often a function of a failing blend door, and could also be a defrost failure. Do you get any ice in the fridge cabinet, like on the back or bottom?  (You should also provide the model of fridge.)

Comment: There's isn't any ice inside the refrigerator, just in the food and beverages within.

Comment: So what fridge is it?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.applianceblog.com/mainforums/threads/rb215lash-samsung-fridge-getting-too-cold.50098/ https://www.appliancepartspros.com/repair-help/samsung-refrigerator-rb215lash-xaa-0000-repair/rb215lashxaa0000-fridge-too-cold.html

Answer (score 1):

Most refrigerators have a damper between the freezer and refrigerator section. That damper can freeze up if a lot of moisture gets into the freezer and not close to reduce the cold air from entering into the lower section. The auto defrost usually won't operate long enough to solve this. A hair dryer is all that's needed to free the damper up.

Answer (score 1):

I have a newer Samsung refrigerator (RS22T556) which isn't the same as yours, but uses similar internals.  Their cooling system, marketed as "twin cooling" or "all-around cooling" uses separate refrigerant zones for each compartment rather than blending cold air from the freezer.

I had exactly the same overcooling issue with my refrigerator side.  For whatever reason, the freezer compartment was always within a degree or so of the displayed temp, but the fridge was routinely 10-15 degrees colder.

I was able to fix it by entering developer mode and adjusting the offset for the fridge side temperature sensor, eventually getting it to the point where the internal temperature was the same as the set/display temperature.

I'd run you through what I did to fix mine, but the two appliances have completely different controls so it wouldn't help you.  Mine has the Family Hub (giant ridiculous screen in the door) so it required screen taps in the correct places and order to get into developer mode.

Since you seem to be already on the right track, I'd go ahead with your Youtube instructions for testing your temperature sensors.  See if you can find any way to enter a diagnostic or developer mode in your specific control system.

Comment: The refrigerator started working normally, with the refrigerator within a couple degrees of the set point.  I double checked and mine is twin cooling like yours, so it's not a damper issue.  I did download the service manual for the unit looking to see if I could change the offset, but I don't know if it makes sense now.  I wonder if this points to an issue with the thermister.